# Routing FQDN to Web Server on Specific Port

Tags: iptables, routing, mac-osx-server

I am running multiple web servers on a single machine.

```
localhost:9000

localhost:8080
```

I want external requests (from the open net) to `mysite.com` to route to port 9000 and `myevenbettersite.com` to port 8080.

I know the system hosts file does not accept ports so it cannot be used as a solution.

Would IpTables be the proper fit for this?

I would ultimately rather use something like the Mac Server or a Linux GUI to do this for more complex configurations.

> This question is clearly about networking so *is* on-topic.  What do you guys not like about the question?

Comment: I suggest this be moved to stackoverflow.com.  Still a bit unclear why this info would be off-topic here since it ***is about networking***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do this with DNS, IPtables or the hosts file.

You'd need to point those domains to a proxy, or something that has knowledge of what you want done, which will in turn re-direct the clients to the "right" place.

Comment: And what would this "something" be?

Comment: Could be Apache, Nginx, HAProxy, or even just a simple script on the web server which can detect the `Host` header and return a `Location` header to redirect the clients.

Comment: I know Apache can do this, but I am running a different webserver, and in this case multiple servers for each site (on a single machine), but it doesn't make much sense to run a webserver just to route to another webserver.

Comment: I guess you'd have to pick one of the already installed web servers, have it be the default landing spot for all the sites, and then redirect to the right port/site. However, if you wanted to "hide" the actual ports from the users, then using a reverse proxy will do the trick because it can look at the `host` header and transparently redirect the requests to the "right" server.

Comment: I think I can see the problems/solutions now.  The webserver in question is the built-in default one the Play Framework uses.  I will probably have to switch this to LightHttpd or Nginx to unify services and solve my problem.

Comment: Yup, you've got to have something sitting between the users and your web servers to do the redirection. The good part, is that if you have this extra piece, you can get a lot more out of it, but that of course depends on your use case and needs.